# What software can create OS image backups for platform independent servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, centos, backup-restoration, image

I have a couple servers for which I use the inbuilt backup tools to make OS backups, is there software that can automate the process and make similar format backups. Are there any freeware tools available, paid software will do too.

**Edit**:I have a couple of CentOS and Windows Server 2008 R2 servers

Comment: @Rajat I have added the info to the post, and I would like a solution that could cover both operating systems please.

Comment: For CentOS you use mondorescue or revisor for win 2k8 R2 there is paid one from symantec

Comment: isn't there a solution that is platform independent?

Comment: mondorescue.org work with all most all the distro linux for revisor i have use for Fedora only

Answer (score 1):

[Bacula](http://bacula.org) is available for all unix-likes and Windows, and can backup in OS-native format as well as in a compatible format (tossing e.g. NTFS ACL etc.). It works great, handles also tape libraries, but is a bit tricky to configure.

[Documentation link](http://bacula.org/en/?page=documentation) You have to read this, because you have to understand and test your backups.

[Bacula answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bacula) on serverfault

Comment: any configuration guides available?

Comment: don't know any besides bacula's own documentation

Answer (score 0):

Look into Acronis software. They have a ton of software suites that you can use for this purpose.